# Saving and retrieving int in ImageButton tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I need to save an integer into the tag of an ImageButton. But I am getting a crash each time I try to read the data back.

to save I do, for example,

```
tokenBtn.setTag(View.INVISIBLE);
```

then to read I do

```
Integer tag = (Integer) tokenBtn.getTag();
```

Here is the error for `getTag()`

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Please post your complete logs

Comment: Are you using Glide library to load image to this particular view? Perhaps it uses `View.setTag()` to store its object of `GenericRequest` class which overrides your integer?

Comment: @Aruziell you should post your comment as an answer so it could be flagged as the correct answer and this post is marked as solved

Comment: @ShinyDarkStone You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good.

I suspect the problem is Glide library which overrides your integer using its `GenericRequest` object in order to load image.

I came up with this idea seeing `ClassCastException` error message.